# How to add more columns to dataframe extracting the columns that are inside one column which came from a CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, parsing

**As recommended, I reduced the amount of text and optimized the question.**

> I have a .CSV with multiple columns, okay, that's normal, but one of the columns have multiple columns inside, and I'm trying to get those columns out and add it as new columns to the dataframe, to work with it.

## Just to ilustrate, this is the format of the table coming from the CSV:

[image: just to ilustrate, look into second column]

**Those keys need to be new columns and the values new rows.**

## In the end, I would like something like this:

[image: The second column is now integrated to the DF as new columns]

- This is the **first row of the CSV**, it contains **the name** of the columns:

> time,"labels_stats","lockers","keys","panels","glass","std_glass","avg_glass","sand","std_sand","avg_sand","gas","std_gas","avg_gas","temperature","std_
> temperature","avg_
> temperature","cracks","std_cracks","avg_cracks","cracks_forjed"

---

- Here is the second row, **where de values begins**(*it begins in second row and goes until row 8500*):

> If you look closer, will realize that in the respective **second column values**, exists another columns inside with some sort of values. To be clear, they are inside one big quotation mark, **begining** in the **"color=123(...)** and finishing in the **(..),std_box=101"**.

- **Highlighting** the column that has **multiple columns inside**:

> column1,**"color=123,brightness=16,rowling=9,rowling_gone=5,clipper=304,avg_clipper=19,std_clipper=51.917883880861964,billedclipper=152,avg_billedclipper=9.5,std_intensity=25.958941940430982,billedbox=2,avg_billedbox=0.125,std_billedbox=0.3415650255319866,box=4,avg_box=0.25,std_box=0.6831300510639732
> color=1251,brightness=33,rowling=2,rowling_gone=13,clipper=0,avg_clipper=0,std_clipper=0,billedclipper=0,avg_billedclipper=0,std_intensity=0,billedbox=0,avg_billedbox=0,std_billedbox=0,box=0,avg_box=0,std_box=101"**,"column3","column4","column5",column6,columnN

---

**EDIT-1**
Tried the first solution sugested by **lil-solbs**:

```
attrs_df = pd.DataFrame(
df["labels"].apply(
    lambda x: {
        y.split("=")[0]: y.split('=')[1] for y in x.split(',')
    }
  ).to_list()
)
attrs_df
```

It's almost there, it retrieves only the first color attributes and creates a new dataframe, but it doesn't extract the other colors and their respective attributes. And the name of the columns should end with the color value(*everything in only one dataframe*), like:

> "color123","brightness123","rowling123","rowling_gone123"(...),"color1251","brightness1251","rowling1251","rowling_gone1251"(...)

---

---

**EDIT-2**

> The sugestion made by **Corralien** worked!!!! I took the code and edit with the sugestion made by his comments, thankyou very very much @Corralien!!!
> Thankyou too @lil-solbs!!!

### The solution:

```
# Extract labels_stats Series and flatten it
df1 = (df.pop('labels_stats').str.split().explode()
         .str.extractall(r'(?P<key>[^=]+)=(?P<val>[^,]+),?')
         .droplevel('match'))

# Add the numeric id (123, 1251, etc)
df1['key'] += df1['val'].where(df1['key'] ==             
'color').ffill().astype(str)

# Reshape the dataframe as the original one
df1 = df1.pivot_table(index=df1.index, columns='key', values='val', 
sort=False, aggfunc='first')

# Get the expected output
out = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
```

Comment: For a same color group (123, 5258, etc), you have two std_clipper attributes with different values. What do you want to do with this 2 values. You should have only unique column names. Difficult to create `std_clipper5228` twice.

Comment: Yes, I would have two attributes values, and it's meaningful to to have two, because they are unique to that color. I need unique attributes values to each color. Every color have 16 attributes.

Comment: No. For color123 and other colors, you have 2 std_clipper not only one.

Comment: You're right, it was a mistake that I've made when was anonymizing the data, so, imagine that's only one std_cilpper for each color. The fact is that every color has 16 attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to process your column separately:

```
# Extract labels_stats Series and flatten it
df1 = (df.pop('labels_stats').str.split().explode()
         .str.extractall(r'(?P<key>[^=]+)=(?P<val>[^,]+),?')
         .droplevel('match'))

# Add the numeric id (123, 1251, etc)
df1['key'] += df1['val'].where(df1['key'] == 'color').ffill().astype(str)

# Reshape the dataframe as the original one
df1 = df1.pivot_table(index=df1.index, columns='key', values='val', sort=False)

# Get the expected output
out = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                  time       lockers       keys     panels       glass     std_glass   avg_glass           sand    std_sand  ...  std_clipper80  billedclipper80  avg_billedclipper80  billedbox80  avg_billedbox80  std_billedbox80   box80  avg_box80   std_box80
0  03/24/2018 00:00:00  77787.172081  97.857143  33.714286  686.967347  35284.503611  317.196164  937679.620975  181.610782  ...   89590.988446         293454.0          3811.090909       2879.0         37.38961       297.097457  7217.0  93.727273  765.390606

[1 rows x 124 columns]
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the effort, I tried this solution, but the "out" is a dataframe with the same columns of de original df, excpet by the "label_stats" column, which was removed, it's with 20 columns, and not 124 columns as expected.

Comment: What is the output of `df1`. Do you have all columns?

Comment: It came out with this warning too: 

/tmp/ipykernel_97682/3551541699.py:10: FutureWarning: Dropping invalid columns in DataFrameGroupBy.mean is deprecated. In a future version, a TypeError will be raised. Before calling .mean, select only columns which should be valid for the function.
  df1 = df1.pivot_table(index=df1.index, columns='key', values='val', sort=False)

Comment: Try `df1 = df1.pivot_table(index=df1.index, columns='key', values='val', sort=False, aggfunc='first')`

Answer (score 0):

This is not elegant, but starting with a dummy df like yours:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {"time": 10, "labels": "color=123,brightness=456"}, 
    {"time": 10, "labels": "color=234,brightness=567"}
])
```

You can apply a lambda to split the `labels` column and make a new DataFrame like this:

```py
attrs_df = pd.DataFrame(
    df["labels"].apply(
        lambda x: {
            y.split("=")[0]: y.split('=')[1] for y in x.split(',')
        }
    ).to_list()
)
attrs_df
```

`attrs_df`:

```py
  color brightness
0   123 456
1   234 567
```

From there you can join the two DataFrames. If I had more time I'd make that more elegant. Maybe I'd use [cross-sections](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) for the first time if even possible

EDIT: Reading your question better (lots of text) I see you have multiple colors and want the `color=value` to have `value` in the rows. It's a small tweak to above, but `attrs_df` would not split the key on `=`, but just be the key:

```py
pd.DataFrame(
    df["labels"].apply(
        lambda x: {
            y: y.split('=')[1] for y in x.split(',')
        }
    ).to_list()
)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks to try to help-me. I tried your idea but it partially worked, I could get the 15 16 attributes related to the color123, but couldn't get it from the other colors, like, the next color after color123 is color1251, and it's attributes. When I tried, the new dataframe was composed only by color123 attributes.

Comment: @Pdr I updated my anser to hopefully work better with your use case

Comment: Thanks. I tested it, but now it's creating new columns to each rows that is beeing extracted, then, I ended up with more than 35k columns hahaha. Sorry for the lot of text, I'm not used to post on StackOverFlow, didn't knew the best way to do it.

Comment: I recommend stripping your question down to the minimum amount of data to produce your problem. The lambda above is close to what you need and I'm curious if you tried tweaking it.